# Calcular área de poligono plano trazado en el mapa Android API V2

Tags: android, google-maps, textarea

Necesito saber cómo calcular el área de un polígono trazado en el mapa de google API V2 usando androis studio, pero suponiendo que es perfectamente plano, que no se tome en cuenta la altura del terreno, porque para eso está la libreria de Spherical.Util, pero a mí me urge calcular el área como si el terreno fuera perfectamente plano.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Muestra lo que has intentado y qué problemas has tenido. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.